# Specific Angular Cli Version is not installed

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I need to install Angular CLI in the version 1.6.8. When I am executing this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8
```

it is getting installed well. But when I am check the version using `ng -v`, it displays the latest version, in my case `1.7.4`.

For my code compatibility, I need version `1.6.8`. And even in my dependencies in `package.json`, I have specified the cli as version `1.6.8` :

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.8"
```

Does anybody know the issue? How can I install version 1.6.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are inside a directory that has node_modules `ng -v` would report that version, not the global one. For updating your global CLI, move to a directory that doesn't have node_modules installed and then execute

```
npm uninstall -g @angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8
```

You can change the version of the angular-cli in the package.json if you want to stick to the particular version remove the ^ symbol but this would be local

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.8"
```

^ it means update the minor and patch version to the latest and keep the major version same.

Answer (score 1):

This command will install the CLI globally on your machine.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8
```

So, if you have an application that already has CLI version 1.7.4 included in it, you will see that version when you run `ng -v`. If you would like to downgrade to an earlier version, change the version in the *package.json* to the **exact** version you would like to use, and run `npm install`.

In your *package.json* you have this:

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.8"
```

What you need to change it to is this:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.8"
```

Remove the caret from the version number.

The caret tells `npm` that is can install versions of a library higher than what is listed, but only if the version is a minor or patch change. So, going from version 1.6.8 to 1.7.4 is OK, but it won't jump to version 6.0.0 when that comes out.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) for more details.